# How to get the Number of failed Tests as Environment variable in jenkins and pass the number to a triggered job

Tags: jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a regression Job in Jenkins (Surefire tests). I would like to get the number of tests failed and pass it to a next job.

I tried **Regression_Failers = ${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"}** in *Trigger parameterized build on other projects* plugin but it actually passes the whole thing as a string to next job.

Comment: can you expand on "the whole thing"?

Comment: Well. my Jenkins setup is. I have 2 Jobs, 1st job runs JUnit tests using Maven surefire plugin. 2nd Job creates a Git tag on a branch. I want to pass the number of failure from 1st Job to the 2nd with the help of Jenkins parameters and based on this value the 2nd job should create a Tag.

I am not able to retrieve the number of failures in the test in 1st job. This is what I want to pass to the 2nd Job

Comment: sorry, i meant when you specifically mentioned "the whole thing" in your question, i wasn't sure what that meant.

Comment: Ahh, I ment "${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"}" as a string literal value of the parameter Regression_Failers to the next Parameterized job.

So basically, it did not evaluated that as a value

Comment: There is no direct method to get that value. From your test scripts you have to create a properties file in workspace with results, after that you can use [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to create environment values from created properties file. Another way you have to use Groovy scripts to read the data from the TestResultsAction class.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, So I have a post build step to send eMail which uses these parameters, How do they get access to this values? Just wondering ...

Comment: the post build step that sends email is the only thing with access to these values, since they are implemented in the email-ext plugin, https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/content/TestCountsContent.java.

Comment: I think my last resort is to do some 'grep' and extract the information I need from the local file